# C# Visual Studio Project Properties & MSBuild Macros

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Why can't I use MSBuild macros in a C# Project's properties? These all work find in a CPP project.

For example:

- Create an empty C# console application
- Change the main method to take command line arguments
- Right click on the project in solution explorer and click properties
- Choose "Debug" on the left side
- In Command Line Argument's, enter: "$(SolutionDir)"
- Debug your program
- Notice that the argument is quite literally $(SolutionDir) rather than what it translates to.

I have the same problem with "Xml documentation file path" and other fields.

Comment: I expect the UI is just quoting the values in dialog boxes. What happens if you edit the project file directly instead?

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot even find the debug startup arguments in the csproj file. Perhaps they are saved somewhere else?

Comment: I suspect they're in the csproj.user file.

Comment: You were correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Christopher Pisz, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @Daisy that works, if you want to write up an answer, I can mark this answered. Still have no idea why they'd make visual studio work one way for cpp and another for c# in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I use MSBuild macros in a C# Project's properties? These all work find in a CPP project.

This is because the way C# and CPP project introduce macros is not the same.

For C# project, it introduced by the `.props`, `.targets` files, for example, the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file. In your project file `.csproj` you will find following Import:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

For CPP project, it introduced by property sheets, you can get it from `View`->`Other Windows`->`Property Manager`, which is not supported by C# project.

**The different:**

> You can use property sheets to create project configurations that can
> be applied to multiple projects since **project settings that are
> defined in .vsprops files are inheritable**, unlike project settings
> defined in Project Files (.vcproj files). Therefore, **a project
> configuration defined in a .vcproj file can inherit project settings
> from one or more property sheets (.vsprops files)**. For more
> information, see Property Inheritance.

That the reason why you can use MSBuild macros in a CPP Project's properties but not in C# project.

You can check following document for some more details:

[Common macros for build commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties)

[Property Sheets (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/a4xbdz1e(v%3Dvs.90))

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. I understand property sheets and target files and how prop sheets are not available in C# projects. However, I don't know what that all has to do with the UI translating MSBuild macros in projects for cpp, but not for c#. I think you might have explained it, but I am not following it.